# Dart - Values in a Static typed List

Tags: dart, dart-editor, dartium

Why is this not an error in Dart?

```
List<String> listA = ['aa', 1, 'cc']; //not compile time error, not run time error??
```

I am using Dart Editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing `List<String> listA = ['aa', 1, 'cc'];` is like writing `List<String> listA = <dynamic>['aa', 1, 'cc'];`. The `runtimeType` of `['aa', 1, 'cc']` is `List` which is compatible with the type annotation `List<String>` you used.

If you want to define a list of `String` to have a warning in editor and an error at runtime you should prefer :

```dart
List<String> listA = <String>['aa', 'cc'];
// or
final listA = <String>['aa', 'cc'];
```

To better understand here's some samples :

```dart
print((['aa', 1, 'cc']).runtimeType);       // List
print((['aa', 'cc']).runtimeType);          // List
print((<dynamic>['aa', 'cc']).runtimeType); // List
print((<String>['aa', 'cc']).runtimeType);  // List<String>

List<int> l1 = ['aa', 1, 'cc'];         // ok
List<int> l2 = ['aa', 'cc'];            // ok
List<int> l3 = <dynamic>['aa', 'cc'];   // ok
List<int> l4 = <String>['aa', 'cc'];    // warning in editor + runtime error
```

Comment: Thx. `List<String> listA = <String>['aa', 1, 'cc'];` did give me a warning in editor and runtime error. Is it true that `dart2js` won't stop compiling becuz of errors like this? Why is this not a compile time error?